# Gridview list items in android

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I have set gridview with 2 columns the values are coming up properly but when showing the text, if the text is goes to the second line the column 1 size is small and column 2 size is bigger. I am not sure why this is happening? I have set everything Match_Parent.

This is will give an idea of what I trying to say:

[image]

Did you notice the red circle. Row number 3, column 1 is smaller compared to Row number 3 column 2 why? How to make all the column to stay same?

Here is my gridview.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded,NestedWeights" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/nocontantdata"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <GridView
       android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"  >
    </GridView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagefooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/footer_band"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my itemsRow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/itemsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layoutbackground"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/friends"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blackText"
        android:text="@string/profile_text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Give fixed height of RelativeLayout in itemsRow.xml suppose "150dp"

Comment: If I do that wont be an issue on different resolution phones. I mean will it be the same.

Comment: Yes you just fixed the height of that RelativeLayout and will remain same for every device

Comment: Hey! I changed from match_parent to 150dp also tried 200dp still the same. the size is not getting bigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/itemsLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/layoutbackground"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/friends"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profileText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blackText"
    android:text="@string/profile_text"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: LinearLayout being Wrap or 150dp doesn't make a difference. It is the TextView which made the difference :)

Comment: Yes.And I just give you a sample.. Various way is there to solve it..:)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to keep the items the same size, you can make only one line of text visible. Change/add the parameter maxlines = 1 to your textView and this will keep them all the smaller size.  The Relative layout height for your items should be set to wrap-content, not sure if this will make a difference thou.